# Finite resolution for non-regular schemes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, coherent-sheaves

Over varieties that satisfy resolution property, the fact that every coherent sheaf has a finite resolution by vector bundles is equivalent to the variety to be regular. I was wondering whether the finite resolution property has been studied for non-regular varieties? More precisely let's say we have variety that is not regular but it is Gorenstein (and is quasi-projective). Is there any nice family of coherent sheaves that admit finite resolution property? I am mostly interested in reflexive/$S_2$ coherent sheaves that are vector bundles outside of a codimension 2 subvariety.

Comment: On a Cohen-Macaulay surface, a reflexive sheaf with a finite resolution is locally free by the Auslander-Buchsbaum formula.